# separate array object according to date

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a array of events with unixtimestamp and i want to show them according to year. Mean section wise.

```
2015
  Event 1
  Event 2
  Event 3
2014
  Event 1 
  Event 2
  Event 3
```

What i do:

```
        $yearlyEvents=array();
        foreach ($events as $event) {
            $eventPost = get_post($event->post_id);
            $timestamp=$event->start;
            $eventYear=gmdate("Y", $timestamp);
            if($index=in_array($eventYear, $yearlyEvents, true)){
                print_r($index);
            }
            else{
                $tempObj['name']=$eventYear;
                $tempObj['events']=$event;
                $yearlyEvents[]=$tempObj;
            }
        }
```

But not get the desired results.Anybody help?

Comment: `if($index=in_array($eventYear, $yearlyEvents, true))` seems like always true statement. Why don't you put the `eventYear` as a key?

Comment: @RoyalBg can you give me clear example how to handle it year as key..

Comment: `$yearlyEvents[$eventYear][] = array("name" => $name, "events" => $event)`

Comment: Thanks @RoyalBg i am going to do like this.

Comment: I believe this date is saved in a custom field. Query all posts sorted by custom field, and then display year inside the loop

Comment: @RoyalBg its work like charm thanks.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get events as sub arrays of year.

Add sub arrays, one for each year append events to it.

This is my preferred logic, please feel free to change it in accordance with your project needs.

Corrected Code:

```
$yearlyEvents=array();
foreach ($events as $event) {
  $eventPost = get_post($event->post_id);
  $timestamp=$event->start;
  $eventYear=gmdate("Y", $timestamp);
  if($index=in_array($eventYear, $yearlyEvents, true)){
    print_r($index);
  }
  else{
    $tempObj['name']=$eventYear;
    $tempObj['events']=$event;
    $yearlyEvents[$eventYear][] = $tempObj; // Check here.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to get result from Database in such a format which is easy to manipulate for your output.

Here you are trying to display events years wise in descending order and events in ascending order. So first of all get result from database like

```
SELECT * FROM events ORDER by events.start DESC,events.post_id ASC
```

Now it is in an order which is easy to display. loop through and display result until next year found. check if next year come display year too.